# How to make a javascript function that will stop running after 20 seconds?

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to javascript and I'm trying to write a function that will run after the user clicks a button and count the amount of times the user clicks on images on the page and I want it to stop counting after 20 seconds, how do I make a function that will stop running after 20 seconds?

Comment: please post the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: Sounds like you want to set a timeout

Comment: I assume you know that you cannot have a function that actually runs for 20 seconds. The user won't be able to click anything as long as the function runs. What you want is to record the start time and compare the current time regularly against the start time.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ alert("This text is shown after 20 seconds"); }, 20000);`